# draw network topology (php/jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, networking, topology

I work for the small ISP.
We need to draw **network topology** in our project for network management.
I usually have this data:

> "cisco"
>       | => "d-link"
>       | => "d-link"

and so on...

So. Using PHP and jQuery how can i draw simple but nice topology picture?
Thanks in advance! Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP, you could call out to [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) to make the images. There's probably a PHP wrapper for Graphviz already written out there, but it's pretty easy to call it yourself.

For example, this input file (in `example.dot`):

```
digraph example {
    dlink1 [label="d-link"];
    dlink2 [label="d-link"];
    cisco -> dlink1;
    cisco -> dlink2;
}
```

Can be converted into an image:

```
$ dot -Tpng -o example.png example.dot
```

Here's the result:

[image: Result from Graphviz]

Comment: and you can make output in svg format + each of node and link can be shown as a link

Comment: very interesting. need some "on the fly" method to use it without command line...

Comment: @skater_nex: I was suggesting you have PHP run that command whenever it needed to generate a graph. Alternatively, you could try to find some extension that lets Graphviz run within the PHP process.

Comment: I use pear Image_GraphViz to generate graph within PHP. http://pear.php.net/package/Image_GraphViz @skater_nex